# How is Raoult's law independent of the amount of liquid?

Tags: thermodynamics, physical-chemistry

Consider a room filled with air and containing a vessel filled with pure liquid A. Now, the vessel  is opened and liquid A exerts a partial pressure on the room from the equilibrium of liquid and vapor of A. What I'm wondering is how the partial pressure exerted by A is unaffected by the amount of A in the vessel. What if the vessel contained only a few molecules of liquid A, how could this exert the exact same partial pressure as a vessel filled with many moles of liquid A?

From Raoult's law,
$$p_i=p_i^*x_i$$
in either case the liquid mole fraction $x_i$ should remain constant as the only liquid is liquid A. Similarly, the vapor pressure $p_i^*$ is a constant (assuming the room remains at the same temperature and pressure). Thus, the partial pressure of A would remain constant? Combining Dalton's law, the mole fraction of A in the air in either case would also remain the same; however, intuition would have me thinking that the vessel with only a few molecules of A should have a far less mole fraction of A in vapor phase.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's unambiguously a chemistry question and is more suitable for Chemistry SE.

Comment: There is not immediately an equilibrium between liquid and vapor when container "A" is initially opened.  Liquid "A" must evaporate until this equilibrium is established.

Answer (score 2):

If there is not enough liquid in the container it will all have  evaporated before there is enough vapour in the room to have a pressure that equals the equilibrium vapour pressure of the liquid. As long as there is liquid left, and it is in equilibrium with the vapour in the room, the  pressure exerted by the vapour will be the vapour pressure of the liquid.  If the vapour had higher pressure than the vapour pressure at that temperature, it will  condense on the walls and elsewhere.  If the vapour has lower pressure than the equilibrium vapour pressure,  the  liquid in the container will tend to evaporate.